# Using jQuery to apply CSS properties to headers with a specific font family?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm working on a custom Wordpress theme that includes 2 different fonts used for header tags throughout the site. The one font is cursive and needs to be have normal `text-transform` properties. The other font needs to always be displayed in `text-transform:uppercase;`.

I can't apply `text-transform:uppercase;` to all of the header tags because it will also apply to the cursive font - which I do not want.

Since it's Wordpress, the client will be able to add headers in TinyMCE and change the font family on a case-by-case basis, so using a class to apply the cursive font that also applies `text-transform:normal;` is also out.

I was wondering if there is a way to use jQuery to apply the 'text-transform' property to anything with a specific font family?

So, for example, I want to have any header that is `font-family:"Cinzel";` to also have `text-transform:uppercase;` applied to it, but any headers with `font-family:"Dancing Script";` need to remain `text-transform:normal;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter the header tags based on font-family, and then apply the text-transform

```js
$('header').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('font-family').replace("'",'') === 'Cinzel';
}).css('text-transform', 'uppercase');
```

```css
.cinz {font-family : "Cinzel"}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="cinz">this should be uppercase</header>
<header>this shouldn't</header>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass a variable in the filter callback? ```.filter(function(x) { return x.css...``` Or is there a benefit to using ```$(this)```?

Comment: @BenjaminDowns - doesn't really matter